# Drawing Charts on web and mobile App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

I'm developing a web app that needs to display various types of data as charts (pie, line, bar, bubble, etc) depending on the type of data.

Also I will have to develop a mobile app with the same charts.

I started a pilot using google charts, but the client does not like the way they look. And asked me if I can find other library, even if it is not open source ro free.

So I need to find a chart library with great look and fill, that would work an all major web browsers and mobile OS's and that handles different types of charts.

I've been looking at Sencha touch charts, gRaphael, Highcharts, Jquery Visualize and others and I can decide wich one would be btter for this.

Please, I need suggestions about them and why do you think they might be better for the type of project I'm dealing with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody can recommend a specific charting package without fully understanding your requirements.  Also, "shopping" questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by shooping question. I'm asking for others to share their experience with charts libraries. I'll change tha pay for it part. What I meant was that it doesn't have to be free or open source.

Comment: @Ateszki, We don't know what type of project you're dealing with.  All you've mentioned is that you need pie charts, line charts, bar charts, etc., which to me seems like the Google Visualization APIs will work fine.  You need to be much more specific in your requirements.

Comment: If your client already rejected Google charts then you should determine why..and then based upon that review the charting applications you have already mentioned. Prototype another and work with the client until you have a workable solution.

Comment: My client rejected Google charts because he didn't liked the look and feel of them. So I can find one that looks better, but Google charts seemed to souit the job, and I don't know the rest of them. That's why I'm asking for recomendations.

Comment: @Ateszki - you should be asking your client ... not us.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I just wanted to know others experiences on this technology, but it seems that this is not the way to ask. Thanks to everyone and apologies for my question.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using highcharts js and have been very happy so far.